# Delete/Disable DLC Euro Truck Simulator 2?

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

I wish to use the Java Map mod. But, in the description I **MUST** disable the Vive La France DLC. My question is: can I disable the Vive La France DLC?

**Edit:** [Here is a translation of the website requesting I disable the Vive La France DLC](https://translate.google.co.id/translate?sl=id&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=id&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fd-official.blogspot.co.id%2F2017%2F08%2Fbase-map-jowo-v7.html&edit-text=&act=url)

Comment: ...Huh? Why we you trying to get rid of the dlc?

Comment: because, if i using "Vive La France" with Javanese Map Mod, this game can crash

Answer (score 7):

Unchecking the "Installed" checkbox either through the game's library or properties (DLC tab - Enabled checkbox) page should do the trick.

Comment: Remember that if you disable an official DLC, you have to create a new game profile.